# How Can you read GPS data from GlobalSat ND-100S USB GPS Dongle in a windows metro app

Tags: gps, windows-store-apps

I've read jerry nixon's post on the topic
http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/05/metro-answers-can-i-use-serial-port.html
and the conclusion i've come to is you can but only sometimes, now i've come across this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/12/03/my-gps-sensor-is-not-working-with-windows-store-apps.aspx and it seems to tackle the exact problem i have just with a different device.

i have not been able to come up with a solution for: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003WNHGAO/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003WNHGAO) so i'm really hoping that some else has.

I've looked for this GNSS driver, but with no luck. Does anyone have any experience working with this device and a windows 8/8.1 metro app?

Otherwise I think my only recourse will be just to build my app as a regular WPF application.

When the drivers are installed for this dongle you communicate with it via a comm port (virtual serial port)
[image]

then you can list all the available com ports using

```
public static void ListComPorts()
{
    // Get a list of serial port names. 
    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

    // Display each port name to the console. 
    foreach (string port in ports)
        Console.WriteLine(port);
}
```

now since the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace is not available for metro style apps, i'm kind of stuck.

any help would be appreciated it even if that is "Throw in the towel and go with a WPF Application."

Answer (score 1):

You can try the driver here:
http://www.turboirc.com/gps7/

It can turn COM port GPS device into Sensors in system manager, then you can use it as a normal GPS sensor.